# SQL code is not comparing variables given by TKinter from within a function

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, tkinter

The program I'm currently working on should take two inputs given during a function and use them during another function to verify a user, this is done using Tkinter and SQL but the SQL either throws up an error or does not print or progress at all despite it being coded to do so, currently the result it should give is printing True when the password give and the result of the SQL match, I'm wondering if either the SQL is jankey or the way I've set up the variables is, either way I'm beating my head against trying to figure it out so any help would be appreciated, I'm fairly sure the problem is only with the submitlog fuction if that narrows down any issues.

```
import sqlite3  #necessary to use databse searching
import os    #necessary to check the date listed by the system
from tkinter import *    #necessary to use the GUI design features
from tkinter import messagebox #needed for message boxes

login = False #needed to start the login procedure
root =Tk() #defines the foundations for a created page
connection1 = sqlite3.connect("Login.db")   #code to read the database and allow crossreferencing of passwords
#connection2

Username = ""
Password = ""

def submitlog(): #a function that will compare and entered username and password with present passwords on the login database
    cursor1 = connection1.cursor()
    for row in cursor1.execute('SELECT Password FROM Login WHERE Username = "{}"'.format(Username.replace('"','""')), (Username))[0]:
        if row  == Password:
            print(True)
        else:
            print(Username)
            print(Password)
            print(row) 

def logOut():
    root.destroy
    exit()

def loginpage(): #defines the creation of a login page
    root.geometry("1000x700")
    root.resizable(False, False)
    root.configure(background = "Black")
    #creation of text frames
    frame_heading = Frame(root)
    frame_heading.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=30, pady=5)
    #creation of entry frames
    frame_entry = Frame(root)
    frame_entry.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10)
    Label(frame_heading, text="Please log in", font=("Arial", 16)).grid(row=0,column=0,padx=0,pady=5) #heading label
    #entry labels
    Label(frame_entry, text="Username: ").grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)
    Label(frame_entry, text="Password: ").grid(row=1,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)
    #text entry fields
    
    UserName = Entry(frame_entry,width=30, bg = "white")
    UserName.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
    PassWord = Entry(frame_entry,width=30, bg = "white")
    PassWord.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
    #placing the submit and log off buttons
    submit_button = Button(root, text = "Submit", width =10, command= submitlog)
    submit_button.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=0,pady=5)
    logout_button = Button(root, text = "Log out", width = 10, command = logOut)
    logout_button.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=0,pady=5)
    root.mainloop()

    Username = UserName.get()
    Password = PassWord.get()
    return Username and Password
```

previous attempts to rectify involve me trying to update the variables in both functions as well as running the login page outside of a function but all attempts resulted in either and an error or no activity at all

Comment: This code produces no output or errors when I run it.

Comment: Don't use string formatting to substitute variables into SQL, use placeholders and `cursor.execute()` parameters.

Comment: `cursor.execute()` doesn't return anything. What are you expecting to get with `[0]` after it?

Comment: @Barmar the string formatting came from another fix to using sql with variables that was more secure than ? and using [0] was a suggestion from a friend who is more experienced at coding than myself in order to fix my use of cursor.execute for using it in for loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use a `for` loop. Assuming usernames are unique, the query either returns a row or it doesn't. So you can call `cursor1.fetchone()` to get that row, then check the password.

You also need to get the username and password from the entry fields when you call `submitlog()`, not when you first create them.

```
def submitlog(): #a function that will compare and entered username and password with present passwords on the login database
    cursor1 = connection1.cursor()
    Username = UserName.get()
    Password = PassWord.get()
    cursor1.execute('SELECT Password FROM Login WHERE Username = ?', (Username,))
    row = cursor1.fetchone()
    if row and row[0] == Password:
        print(True)
    else:
        print(Username)
        print(Password)
        print(row)
```

You'll need to add `global UserName, PassWord` to `loginpage()` so that the variables can be accessed from `submitlog()`.

BTW, `return Username and Password` is not the way you return multiple values from a function. That should be `return Username, Password`. But I doubt the return value is used, so you don't need to return anything.

Comment: Error says that it is not being supplied bindings

Comment: That shouldn't happen with the second argument `(Username,)`. Are you sure the error is coming from this function?

Comment: my mistake I'm viewing on a small screen and so didn't see the end of the line, that's been fixed bu now it gives this: "if row and row[0] == Password:
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable" for the line if row and row[0] == Password

Comment: You forgot the `()` after `fetchone`

Comment: fixed now and it returns "none" instead of True, does this still mean that it worked?

Comment: If `print(row)` prints `None`, it means the username isn't in the table.

Comment: The Username and Password are both in the table I,ve checked each input, is it possible that it's trying to use the given variable as a column name?

Comment: No, that's not possible. Placeholders are treated as literal data, not names.

Comment: You're setting `Username` in `loginpage()`, not when the user clicks the submit button.

Comment: How do I then set the username when the button is clicked?

Comment: I updated the answer several minutes ago.

Comment: The Edit doesn't work because UserName and PassWord are local variables of the loginpage function, one of the first things I tried

Comment: @WeakTexas68965 Did you read the part of the answer where I said you need to use the `global` statement to make them global variables?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps

```
query = 'SELECT Password FROM Login WHERE Username = ?'
cursor.execute(query, (Username,))
results = cursor.fetchall()
for row in results:
    if row[0] == Password:
        print(True)
```

Thanks Barmar for the helpful comments.

Comment: this doesnt seem to work using this code i get this error "line 32, in submitlog
    cursor1.execute(query,(Username))
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'execute'" EDIT this has been resolved as i hadn't put double brackets after cursor = connection.cursor(), but it has given this error "line 32, in submitlog
    cursor1.execute(query,(Username))
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 0 supplied."

Comment: @WeakTexas68965 `(Username)` should be `(Username,)`

Comment: @Barmar its not throwing up any errors any more, but there is still no output

Comment: @WeakTexas68965 If the username isn't found, the loop doesn't do anything. See my answer.